# Why is a lemon from my tree like this?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, lemons

I have had a lemon tree producing lemons for the lasts few years.
I few I picked had weird shapes, but this one looks very strange.
[image]
I'd like to know if it shapes and weird black color it means something about the lemon itself or even the tree. Is it some kind of fungi, or another thing?
[image]
When I cut it open it looked excellent, but is it edible?

Thank you for your help!
Greetings